# Parsing date with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am given a date:

```
2012-10-11T23:14:00-04:00
```

I am using this format for NSDateFormatter to parse:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-ZZ
```

But it returns nil

Comment: Please show the code you are using to do this. It's hard for us to help without that.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake everything relevant is in the post. If you think you need more info, then you problem don't know enough to answer. read below for the answer if curious.

Comment: I'm glad that you got the answer you were looking for, but from the fact that this question was closed it seems pretty clear that I wasn't the only one who thought a bit more explanation would have been warranted. FWIW, I left the comment BECAUSE I saw close votes and downvotes - I was trying to counter them, under the assumption that you would be open to improving the question accordingly.

Comment: Well they thought wrong lol. There really is nothing else that adds more to the question. There's two things needed to parse the date. The date, and the format. And that's what I provided. But I guess they wanted dozens of lines of irrelevant code (like a lot of SO questions). I actually took an extra step to simply the question...I could have just blindy copy pasted my entire function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. If you have a colon in the string you're converting, you must put 5  *Z* characters in the format string, that is the correct usage. Also, you'd never include the +/- as part of the format, since you're not guaranteed to only have dates + or - GMT (at least not when you're talking about a /format/).

So, the correct format string would be `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ`:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-10-11T23:14:00-04:00"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date); // This correctly logs Date: 2012-10-12 03:14:00 +0000
```

Only using two *Z* characters would be the RFC 822 format, and your date string would have to look like: `2012-10-11T23:14:00-0400` (i.e., no hour/minute separator on the time zone offset). The timezone in your example string is ISO-8601. For more information, see: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns